# This page can't be displayed after creating new Web App with root and regular site collection in 2013 SP

Tags: 2013, error

I have created a new Web application with a site collection. When trying to access the site's team template, the message 'this page can't be displayed' is shown.

I have tried recreating it using different ports, creating a new pool and restarting IIS.

Running on Windows 8 Server.

Has anybody got any suggested troubleshooting advice?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a host header while creating a new web application.

For troubleshooting purpose just leave the host header empty and try to create a new web application.

Also a possibility can be that the home page is having some issues.

Try hitting the "/_layouts/settings.aspx" for the newly created root site collection and check if the settings page loads up.

If it does, then the problem is really with the home page.